# API Gateway Lambda authorizers - "Execution failed due to an Authorizer Error" - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

**Summary**

When a Lambda Authorizer is generating a 500 when executing what's the best way to find out what's going on ?

---

**Background**

In API Gateway I have a setup an 'Authorizer' which gets a Lambda function to act as an authorizer.

The Authorizer function expects a header called 'Authorization'.

**Testing in Lambda Console**

When I use the 'Test' function within the Lambda console for the Authorizer I get this output

```
{
  "policyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:111111111111:my-api/prod/GET/my-api/*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
      }
    ]
  },
  "context": {
    "bool": true,
    "number": 1,
    "key": "value"
  },
  "principalId": "user|a1b2c3d4"
}
```

**Testing in API Gateway**

When I then move over to the API Gateway console and use the 'Test' facility (in the 'Resources' panel) for an API endpoint I get a 200 response and the 'Logs' panel doesn't show any errors.

**Error when using cUrl**

It seemed to me that it should now work however when I try to access the endpoint using cUrl I get this :

```
curl --verbose -L https://1234567890.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/my-resource -H 'Authorization:ABCDEFGHIJKL'
```

the output looks like this :

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying XX.XX.XXX.X...
* Connected to 1234567890.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com (XX.XX.XXX.X) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*        subject: CN=*.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
*        start date: 2020-08-30 00:00:00 GMT
*        expire date: 2021-09-29 12:00:00 GMT
*        subjectAltName: 1234567890.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com matched
*        issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; OU=Server CA 1B; CN=Amazon
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /prod/my-resource HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 1234567890.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
> Accept: */*
> Authorization:ABCDEFGHIJKL
>
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Date: Tue, 13 Oct 2020 22:04:04 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 16
< Connection: keep-alive
< x-amzn-RequestId: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
< x-amzn-ErrorType: AuthorizerConfigurationException
< x-amz-apigw-id: ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
```

which I assume means there's some sort of exception being thrown withing the Lambda function when the API endpoint is hit by cUrl and which doesn't occur when the API Gateway 'Test' facility exercises it ?

**Question(s)**

What's the best way to determine where the Lambda Authorizer is having a problem ?

And is there something obvious in what I've described here which might be resulting it the function returning a 500 ?

Comment: I am having the exact issue, did you ever find a remedy?

Comment: @AutoM8R , sorry for slow reply. I'm sorry but I can't recall what happened about this. It wasn't for "work" and so I suspect, once I got blocked, that I may have moved onto something else. If you find an approach that works please answer the question and I'll try it myself.